# Adding range to wp_link_pages()

Tags: pagination, single, wp-link-pages

I have some very long posts, some have more than 50 pages (`<!--nextpage-->`) and when using `wp_link_pages`, it give me 50 internal post links, clearly this isn't usable.

How can I add a range to the `wp_link_pages` function?

The output should look like this: ...4 - 5 - **6** - 7 - 8...

**UPDATE 10/1/2012**:

I've got the logic for adding the range but now I need to figure out how to add it to the existing `wp_link_pages` function?

Here is the example function:

```
function limitPagination(){
    $displayPages = 5;
    $firstPage = 1;
    $lastPage = $numpages > 5;

    while($numpages > $displayPages){
        if(($pageNow > $firstPage +2) && ($pageNow < $lastPage - 2)){
                echo (($pageNow - 2).($pageNow - 1).$pageNow.($pageNow + 1).($pageNow + 2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking for the same thing.